# FileInputStream does not read the correct value?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File f = new File("file.txt");
            f.createNewFile();
            OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);


            fos.write(200);



            System.out.println(fis.read());


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MySimple.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

this prints 200 as expected. however when I write 2000 it reads 208. could please explain why it behaves in this way?

Comment: This method only write a byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method call `fos.write(200);` writes a **byte** of data.  When you write 200, it saves that in an 8 bit value just fine.

But when you try to write 2000, it ignores anything above the first 8 bits. 2000 in binary is `0111 1101 0000`.  But since the top 4 bits are lost, the resulting value written is `1101 0000` or 208 in decimal.

The methods are a bit confusing since `write()` takes an integer value and `read()` returns an integer value.

Comment: i thought it might be because it ignore the bits. However i was expecting to see 127 since byte range is between -127 and +127

Comment: @kaka - you're seeing a little bit of weirdness because the byte is being "upgraded" to an int.  In effect, it makes the byte unsigned.